# Looking for exact match using grep

Tags: bash

Suppose that I have a file like this:

tst.txt

```
fName1 lName1-a  222
fname1 lName1-b 22
fName1 lName1 2
```

And I want to get the 3rd column only for "fName1 lName1", using this command:

```
var=`grep -i -w "fName1 lName1" tst.txt`
```

However this returns me every line that starts with "fName1 lName1", how can I look for the exact match?

Comment: Is space a delimiter you can use in your grep? if so, use it in your grep to prevent "1Name1-a" from being caught

Comment: I tried to use space, but could not manage to make it work.

Comment: Try this: `grep -Po '(?<=fName1 lName1 ).+' tst.txt`

Comment: Could you explain precisely why you could not manage to make the use of space work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(grep -Po '(?<=fName1 lName1 ).+' tst.txt)
echo $var
```

The trick is to use the `o` option of the `grep` command. The `P` option tells the interpreter to use Perl-compatible regular expression syntax when parsing the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(grep "fName1 lName1 " tst.txt |cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Comment: It should and it does: note that the pattern used by grep in this answer has a trailing white space. The answers above this one use the trailing white space to match the line that is required and not the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method:
`grep -i -E  "^fName1 lName1\s" tst.txt | cut -f3,3- -d ' '`
But you must be sure that line starts with `fName1` and you have space after `lName1`.